# Go back on a stack navigator passing params?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

How do I navigation.popToTop() passing params to the initial route?

Inside of my screen I have a FlatList and I want to pass the string title of the list item selected to the initial route of the navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two option to achieve this.

1. Using call back method
   Add a callback method in root class and pass it to the child. Then cll the callBackMethod from child.
2. Add an event listener in root. And emit the listener from child.eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-event-listeners

Hope this will help.

Comment: I went for the second option and it worked! Thank you!